# Illegal string PDO fetch() vs fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

When I try to call `fetch()` after executing a PDO statement, I get the following warning:

> Warning: Illegal string offset

It works perfectly when I use `fetchAll()`, though.

What's the difference between the two, and how would I use either one?

```
$allData = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$allData->execute();
$result = $allData->fetch();
```

Comment: I think (guessing here) that fetch expects one record, and fetchall accepts multiple records

Comment: @hellyale That is correct. `fetch()` is for returning a single row of results, `fetchAll()` returns many rows.

Comment: You haven't actually shown the part of your code that would throw that warning. None of that code refers to an offset, so the warning comes later, when you're doing something with `$result`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes when i  but it in Loop

Comment: What type of loop? Is it a `for` loop, or a `foreach` loop? @HussamAdil Can you show us the code?

Comment: Right. Since `fetch` only returns one row, there's no need for a loop. If you use `fetch` and then iterate `$result`, you're actually iterating over the columns of that one row, you get that warning when you try to index into one of the row's values using a string key.

Comment: My Code is Working Just I'm Looking for That Concept And I found It In your answer Thanks @GrumpyCrouton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is not due to the use of `fetch()` OR `fetchAll()` as neither of these functions are using an `offset`, there must be something you are doing in your code later that is causing this issue.

I believe your issue has to do with the way you are looping through your values as you say that it works when you use `fetchAll()`. Your loop is throwing an error because it is trying to access an offset that does not exist because `fetch()` will only return a single result while `fetchAll()` will return multiple from your query.

---

As for your question "What's the difference between the two (`fetch()` & `fetchAll()`), and how would I use either one?", here is your answer.

[`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) is used to return all relevant rows, according to the query.

This is beneficial for queries where you need many rows of data.

> PDOStatement::fetchAll() returns an array containing all of the
>   remaining rows in the result set. The array represents each row as
>   either an array of column values or an object with properties
>   corresponding to each column name. An empty array is returned if there
>   are zero results to fetch, or FALSE on failure.

---

[`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) is used to return a *single row* of results from your query.

This is beneficial for queries where you only need a single row result. This is useful for things like when a user logs in so you don't have to loop through data to assign it to variables.

> Fetches a row from a result set associated with a PDOStatement object.
>   The fetch_style parameter determines how PDO returns the row.